# Custom Font for Segment control title in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, segment

How can I change the default font for UISegmentControl title?[in Storyboard or Programmatically](https://i.stack.imgur.com/grQrp.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please consider referring to the documentation provided by Apple before asking a question. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisegmentedcontrol UISegmentedControl offers a method called `setTitleTextAttributes` to do that.

Answer (score 0):

1/ Put an IBOutlet

```
@IBOutlet weak var segment: UISegmentControl!
```

2/ Custom

```
segment.setTitleTextAttributes([ NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "YourFont", size: 18.0)! ], forState: .Normal)
```